# Memory capacity on different OS-es

Tags: memory, 64-bit

The manual for my machine (Asus V4-P5G43) reads this under memory limitations.

Due to chipset limitation, this motherboard can only support up to
8 GB on the operating systems listed below. You may install a maximum of
2 GB DIMMs on each slot:

Windows XP Professional x64 Edition
Windows Vista x64 Edition

My question is why this is the case.  I would be using a GNU/Linux system, and wonder if this limitation would matter to me.  Does this mean that some OS-es support less, or could some support more memory?

Comment: What processor would you be using?  The 8GB memory limitation is likely more of a limitation of the chipset then anything.  Its unlikely you will be able to use more than 8GB due to the age of that hardware.

Comment: The processor is this one: Version: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Quad CPU Q8400 @ 2.66GHz. There are for slots for memory on the baseboard.

Answer (score 2):

The 64bit Operating Systems referred to support more than 8GB physical memory. The point being made is that only 8GB can be installed on the motherboard.

32bit Windows client systems only support 4GB (apart from some so-called Starter editions which support less for marketing reasons). 64bit Windows clients have supported various physical memory sizes since Windows XP. The current limit for Windows 8 Professional is 512GB. The limitations for each Windows iteration are detailed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778(v=vs.85).aspx).

The physical limitations of the motherboard mean that no more than 8GB as four 2GB DIMMs can be used with Linux as well.